# How do I anchor the ellipsis to be on the right side in a paragraph using RTL direction?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

My application supports Right-To-Left direction, but numeric values should not be effected by this mode, only customizations-wise like gaps, margin, padding, etc, that means when it truncates,the ellipsis should be shown on the Right side of the paragraph.

For instance, a container with title and value:

```
... html

<div class="container" >
    <p class="label-p" >Budget</p>
    <p class="value-p" >$100,00</p>
</div>

... css

.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container .label-p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: initial;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

// the ellipsis should be shown on the right side in RTL, but it's shown on left side.
.container .value-p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: initial;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

when this container gets smaller than its contents, the "value" paragraph renders an ellipsis on the left side, technically it's correct because the language is setup to RTL, but since it's a numeric field, the ellipsis should be rendered on the right, how do I achieve it?

I Thought that using "direction:ltr" in css could be helpful, but it makes the paragraph customizations be ltr, I also used "lrm;" that was not helpful.